# How can I replace variables in annotation via Kustomize?

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

Any ideas how can I replace variables via Kustomize? I simply want to use a different ACCOUNT_ID and IAM_ROLE_NAME for each overlay.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  annotations:
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::${ACCOUNT_ID}:role/${IAM_ROLE_NAME}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16):

Kustomize doesn't use "variables". The way you would typically handle this is by patching the annotation in an overlay. That is, you might start with a base directory that looks like:

```
base
├── kustomization.yaml
└── serviceaccount.yaml
```

Where `serviceaccount.yaml` contains your `ServiceAccount` manifest:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
    name: my-service-account
    annotions:
      eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: "THIS VALUE DOESN'T MATTER"
```

And `kustomization.yaml` looks like:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
namespace: my-namespace

resources:
  - serviceaccount.yaml
```

Then in your overlays, you would replace the `eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn` annotation by using a patch. For example, if you had an overlay called `production`, you might end up with this layout:

```
.
├── base
│   ├── kustomization.yaml
│   └── serviceaccount.yaml
└── overlay
    └── production
        ├── kustomization.yaml
        └── patch_aws_creds.yaml
```

Where `overlay/production/patch_aws_creds.yaml` looks like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: my-service-account
  annotations:
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::1234:role/production-role
```

And `overlay/production/kustomization.yaml` looks like:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
  - ../../base

patches:
  - patch_aws_creds.yaml
```

With this in place, running...

```
kustomize build overlay/production
```

...would generate output using your production role information, and so forth for any other overlays you choose to create.

---

If you don't like the format of the strategic merge patch, you can use a json patch document instead. Here's what it would look like inline in your `kustomization.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
  - ../../base

patches:
  - target:
      version: v1
      kind: ServiceAccount
      name: my-service-account
    patch: |-
      - op: replace
        path: /metadata/annotations/eks.amazonaws.com~1role-arn
        value: arn:aws:iam::1234:role/production-role
```

I don't think this really gets you anything, though.

Comment: Well-explained, thanks! I'm aware of patching in kustomize, but isn't there any workarounds to use environment variables or easier way other than replicating of the whole ServiceAccount.yaml in all overlays?

Comment: Keep in mind that the only reason you're replicating the "whole serviceaccount" is because it's very, very small. If it were larger (lots of labels, additional annotations, or something like a pod spec) then you wouldn't to replicate it: all you need is the version/kind/name triple to identify it.

Comment: how about if I keep ServiceAccount yaml and just add annotation in kustomization.yaml instead of a patch file? If it is possible, how can I do that? I didn't get to see anything but `commonAnnotations`. But this would add the annotation to all resources I believe. @larsks

Comment: I think you're going to have to follow a patching model, or use a tool other than customize if you want templating features like variable replacement. I've updated the answer with a different patch syntax, but I think the number of required lines is just about identical.

Comment: should it be `patchesStrategicMerge` instead of `patches` over the patch_aws_creds.yaml example?

Comment: No. You use a single `patches` section for both types of patches.

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve this case using json-pointer: ~1

Change the / by ~1 in path:

path: /metadata/annotations/eks.amazonaws.com~1role-arn

Ref:https://jsonpatch.com/#json-pointer

Comment: +1 for drawing attention to this - I didn't pick that up from the example and it wasn't mentioned by the accepted answer!